# Decoding Keyence LJ-X8000 Bitmap-Height Image

Tags: matlab, bitmap, bit-shift, bmp

I have a Keyence Line Laser System LJ-X 8000, that I use to scan the surface of different objects.
The Controller saves the height information as a bitmap, with each pixel representing one height value. After a lot of tinkering, I found out, that Keyence is not using the actual colors, rather than using the 24-Bit RGB-triplets as some form of binary storage. However, no combination of these bytes seems to work for me. Are there any common storage methods for 24-bit Integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decode those values, I did a scan covering the whole measurement range of the scanner, including some out of range values in the beginning and the end. If you look at the distribution of the values of each color plane, you can see, that the first and third plane actually only use values up to 8/16 which means only 3/4 Bits. This is also visible in the image itself, as it mainly shows a green color.

I concluded that Keyence uses the full byte of the green color plane, 3 Bits of the first and 4 Bits of the last plane to store the height information. Keyence seems to have chosen some weird 15 Bit Integer Format to store their data.

With a little bit-shifting and knowing that the scanner has a valid range from [-2.2, 2.2], I was able to build the following simple little (Matlab-) script to calculate the height information for each pixel:

```
HeightValBin = bitshift(scanIm(:,:,2),7, 'uint16') ...
               + bitshift(scanIm(:,:,1),4, 'uint16')...
               + bitshift(scanIm(:,:,3),0, 'uint16');
scanBinValScaled = interp1([0,2^15], [-2.2, 2.2], double(scanBinVal));
```

Keyence offers a software to convert those .bmp into .csv-files, but without an API to automate the process. As I will have to deal with a lot of these files I needed to automate this process.

The calculated values from the rgb triplets are actually even more precise than the exported csv, as the csv only shows 4 digits after the decimal point.

[image: Binary Values of the color planes]

[image]